# Webpage bookmark on desktop

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'd like to have a bookmark for a webpage, shown on my desktop that, when clicked, opens that page. I know there are workarounds (applescript etc.) but is there a direct approach?

I'm using Google Chrome on OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the webpage in your preferred browser, then click on the website's icon on the left of the URL bar and drag it to your Desktop.   This creates a shortcut.

Applescript to create a webpage shortcut seems like the hard way.

Comment: I meant an applescript that creates a new tab/launches chrome with a website prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Easy in Safari, idk in Chrome.

Open bookmarks from the icon top left, to show the sidebar; find appropriate bookmark in the list, drag to desktop. Doesn't work from menus, just from that list.

I can't imagine Chrome being much different.

Answer (score 0):

Most Mac OS X browsers will allow you to drag a website's favicon to your Desktop to create an icon that you can double click to open the site.

However, this will open the link in the Default browser as specified `Safari -> Preferences -> General -> Default web browser` regardless of which app created the desktop icon.

To force opening the link in a specified, browser you need to create an AppleScript.

For Chrome:

```
do shell script "open -a 'Google Chrome' http://example.com"
```

For Firefox:

```
do shell script "open -a Firefox 'http://example.com'"
```

For Safari:

```
do shell script "open -a Safari http://example.com"
```

Pay attention to the different quote methods. "Google Chrome" needs to be wrapped in quotes, a \ to escape a space doesn't work in this context. Firefox needs the URL to be quoted.

Save the script as an AppleScript application.